# Sorting 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, lambda

I have recently come across a problem in which I had to sort a 2 dimensional array by the 0 index of the nested arrays.
`[[2,1],[1,4],[3,5]]` the output should be `[[1,4],[2,1],[3,5]]` I created a solution using lambda function. `array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` I have been wondering **what is the best way to achieve this without using lambda functions?**

Edit - I would also like to be able to choose by what index to sort by

Comment: Have you tried just `array.sort()` ?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. But what if I wanted to sort by the 1st index not 0?

Comment: Is NumPy an option for you? The sort method of an ndarray has the option `axis` that, in the case of an 2D-array, defines if you want to sort by row or column.